# Has the army of Vaikuntha under the command of Vishvaksena ever fought alongside the Devas or humans in wars against Asuras and Rakshasas?

Tags: vishwaksena

Just like the Devas have their own army under the command of Kartikeya, and Shiva has his army of Bhuta Ganas, Vishnu has his own army in Vaikuntha under the command of Vishvaksena, who is a nitya suri, or an eternal inhabitant of Vaikuntha.

Has the army of Vaikuntha under the command of Vishvaksena ever fought alongside the Devas or humans in wars against Asuras and Rakshasas?

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32510/does-vishnu-maintain-a-standing-army

Comment: Yes Vishwaksena’s army has fought alongside humans and devas before. Interestingly, he drives/ drove  the chariot unlike Krishna and like Arjuna, Mahavishnu is the warrior

Comment: Yes. Vishwaksena has fought wars, won wars which you never know about, seen fiery workmen buzzing about in the universe, shown Parabrahman the status quo of The Fiery workman, status quo of planets, travelled to rims of galaxies yet to be discovered, hid things that Vishnu should never know about(although he knows that HE knows), pacified him many a times, ...

Comment: For what possible reason would you need an army of Vaishnava? One of them is plenty for pretty much any winable fight.

Answer (score 1):

1. vishNu does have an army  some of whom were deployed to fight on side of skanda in tArak war [MB shalya parva ch. 45]

> 1. The gods then made over to skanda the celestial host, invincible, abounding with celestial troops, capable of destroying the enemies of the gods, and of forms like that of vishNu.
> 2. The illustrious vishNu gave unto skanda three companions, **chakra and vikram and sankram** of great might.

2. vishNu's avtArs i.e. rAm and krushNa did have armies:

> 1. The earth is thus suffused with those mighty **army generals of vAnar race** whose physiques resembled the clusters of clouds and peaks of mountains, and who have emerged for the reason of helping rAm. [VR bAl khanDa 1-17-37]
> 2. There is a **large body of cowherds** numbering ten crores, rivalling me in strength and known as the **nArAyaNas**, all of whom are able to fight in the thick of battle.[MB udyog parva ch. VII]

3. The name "vishwaksen" is found at many places in both epics i.e. rAmAyaN and mahAbhArat but it is always used as a name of vishNu. As per pAncharAtra scriptures, vishwaksen is considered senapatI just like mahAsen (or devsenApati) and is a personified form of kAlvaishvAnar.

Comment: What is kAlvaishvAnar?